# Take in string, return true if after "a", a "z" appears within three places

Tags: ruby

```
# Write a method that takes a string in and returns true if the letter
# "z" appears within three letters **after** an "a". You may assume
# that the string contains only lowercase letters.
```

I came up with this, which seems logical, but for some reason if "z" comes directly after "a", it returns false. Can someone explain why?

```
    def nearby_az(string)
        i = 0
        if string[i] == "a" && string[i+1] == "z"
            return true
        elsif string[i] == "a" && string[i+2] == "z"
            return true
        elsif string[i] == "a" && string[i+3] == "z"
            return true
        else return false

        end
        i += 1
    end
```

Comment: "z" after "a" is not the problem: `nearby_az('az')` does return `true`.

Comment: The question should show some calls to the function, to show how it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

@shivram has given the reason for your problem. Here are a couple of ways to do it.

**Problem is tailor-made for a regular expression**

```
r = /
    a      # match "a"
    .{,2} # match any n characters where 0 <= n <= 2
    z      # match "z"
    /x     # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

!!("wwwaeezdddddd" =~ r)  #=> true
!!("wwwaeeezdddddd" =~ r) #=> false
```

You would normally see this regular expression written

```
/a.{0,2}z/
```

but *extended* mode allows you to document each of its elements. That's not important here but is useful when the regex is complex.

*The Ruby trick `!!`*

`!!` is used to convert *truthy* values (all but `false` and `nil`) to `true` and *falsy* values (`false` or `nil`) to `false`:

```
!!("wwwaeezdddddd" =~ r)
  #=> !(!("wwwaeezdddddd" =~ r))
  #=> !(!3)
  #=> !false
  #=> true

!!("wwwaeezdddddd" =~ r)
  #=> !(!("wwwaeeezdddddd" =~ r))
  #=> !(!nil)
  #=> !true
  #=> false
```

but `!!` is not really necessary, since

```
puts "hi" if 3   #=> "hi"
puts "hi" if nil #=>
```

Some don't like `!!`, arguing that

```
<condition> ? true : false
```

is more clear.

**A non-regex solution**

```
def z_within_4_of_a?(str)
  (str.size-3).times.find { |i| str[i]=="a" && str[i+1,3].include?("z") } ? true : false
end

z_within_4_of_a?("wwwaeezdddddd")
  #=> true
z_within_4_of_a?("wwwaeeezdddddd")
  #=> false
```

This uses the methods [Fixnum#times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times), [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) and [String#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) (and `String#size` of course).

Comment: `0` is redundant in counters: `/a.{,2}z/` works pretty fine.

Comment: Thanks, mudsie. Edited. That would be especially valuable at [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To be honest, the latter is _not_ non-regex solution, since `include?` uses regex implicitly. I have just posted true c-style non-regex :)

Comment: @mudasobwa, I see [String#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) just uses [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-index), the operative line of the latter being `if (rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "11", &sub, &initpos) == 2)...`, which suggests it's just stepping through the string.

Comment: Indeed; yes, you’re right. Sorry for misleading comment.

Comment: You only have to loop `(str.size - 3).times`

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. After posting that occurred to me too (sort of--I was thinking `-1`, but of course you're right). I was too lazy to fix it then, but now I've no choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is incorrect. You are considering only the case where String starts with `a` (with `i = 0` at the start of your method). I can see you are incrementing `i` at the end, but its of no use as its not in a loop.

I can think of a solution as to find the index of `a` in string, then take substring from that index + 3 and look for `z`. Something like:

```
s = "wwwaeezdddddd"
s[s.index("a")..s.index("a")+3]
#=> "aeez"
s[s.index("a")..s.index("a")+3] =~ /z/ # checking if z is present
#=> 3
```

If `a` can occur more than once in input String, you need to find all indices of `a` and run the above logic in a loop. Something like:

```
s = "wwwaesezddddddaz"
indexes = (0 ... s.length).find_all { |i| s[i,1] == 'a' }
#=> [3, 14]
indexes.each { |i| break if @is_present = s[i..i+3] =~ /z/ }
@is_present
#=> 1
```

Comment: thanks @CarySwoveland for your suggestions. I made changes accordingly :)

Comment: The former solution is incorrect; consider a string is `"aXXXXXaz"`. Even if it were, `s[s.index("a")+1..s.index("a")+3]` might save nanoseconds since `s[s.index("a")]` is definitely ≠ 'z'` :)

Comment: Shivam, I considered your comment and realized where I veered. While basic (mind you, I've been coding for about 3 weeks), adding while string[i] != "a" I += 1 before the if loop made everything work.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s implement the FSM ourselves :)

```
input = "wwwaeezdddddd"
!(0...input.length).each do |idx|
  next unless input[idx] == 'a' # skip unrelated symbols
  current = (idx..[idx + 3, input.length - 1].min).any? do |i|
    input[i] == 'z' # return true if there is 'z'
  end
  # since `each` returns truthy (range itself),
  #   in case of success we return falsey and negate
  break false if current
end

#⇒ true
```

Please note, that the above implementation is `O(length(input))` and does not use any built-in ruby helpers, it is just iterating a string char by char.

Answer (score 0):

While the regexp solution is the most elegant, here is one for completion, which is more in spirit to your original attempt:

```
def nearby_az(string)
    !!(apos = string.index('a') and string[apos,3].index('z'))
end
```

Comment: ...provided there is at most one `"a"` in the string.